# Member references and assignment order of evaluation

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, evaluation

Why does the following crash with a `NullReferenceException` on the statement `a.b.c = LazyInitBAndReturnValue(a);`?

```
class A {
    public B b;
}

class B {
    public int c;
    public int other, various, fields;
}

class Program {

    private static int LazyInitBAndReturnValue(A a)
    {
        if (a.b == null)
            a.b = new B();

        return 42;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.b.c = LazyInitBAndReturnValue(a);
        a.b.other = LazyInitBAndReturnValue(a);
        a.b.various = LazyInitBAndReturnValue(a);
        a.b.fields = LazyInitBAndReturnValue(a);
    }
}
```

Assignment expressions are evaluated [from right to left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx), so by the time we are assigning to `a.b.c`, `a.b` should not be null. Oddly enough, when the debugger breaks on the exception, it too shows `a.b` as initialized to a non-null value.

[image: Debugger on break]

Comment: `b` is referenced in `a.b.c` before it is initialized in `LazyInitB...()`.

Comment: Read the answers before commenting, debugger behavior appears to show something more complex than this is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is detailed in [Section 7.13.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the C# spec.

> The run-time processing of a simple assignment of the form x = y
>   consists of the following steps:
>
> - If x is classified as a variable:
>
>   - x is evaluated to produce the variable.
>   - y is evaluated and, if required, converted to the type of x through an implicit conversion (Section 6.1).
>   - If the variable given by x is an array element of a reference-type, a run-time check is performed to ensure that the value
>       computed for y is compatible with the array instance of which x is an
>       element. The check succeeds if y is null, or if an implicit reference
>       conversion (Section 6.1.4) exists from the actual type of the instance
>       referenced by y to the actual element type of the array instance
>       containing x. Otherwise, a System.ArrayTypeMismatchException is
>       thrown.
>   - The value resulting from the evaluation and conversion of y is stored into the location given by the evaluation of x.
> - If x is classified as a property or indexer access:
>
>   - The instance expression (if x is not static) and the argument list (if x is an indexer access) associated with x are evaluated, and the results are used in the subsequent set accessor invocation.
>   - y is evaluated and, if required, converted to the type of x through an implicit conversion (Section 6.1).
>   - The set accessor of x is invoked with the value computed for y as its value argument.

I think the bottom section (*if x is classified as a property or indexer access*) provides a hint, but perhaps a C# expert can clarify.

A *set accessor* is generated first, then `y` is evaluated (triggering your breakpoint), then the *set accessor* is invoked, which causes a null reference exception.  If I had to guess, I'd say the *accessor* points to the old value of `b`, which was null.  When you update `b`, it doesn't update the accessor that it already created.

Comment: The odd thing is that if you actually debug the code the method `LazyInitBAndReturnValue` actually runs *before* the exception is thrown. I would think the evaluation of a.b.c would cause the exception to be thrown before the method runs because `c` could not be evaluated.

Comment: @CraigW. - I hate adding *guess* answers on StackOverflow, but maybe Eric Lippert will stumble across this question and confirm or disprove my suspicion.  `+1` for the question though!

Comment: I had to read your last paragraph a couple of times but now I get what you're saying. By the time the assignment happens `b` actually contains a value but *internally* the CLR has already stored a reference to `b` from *before* the method was run. When I first looked at the OP's code I thought, "Of course you're going to get a NullRefEx" but then running the code made me scratch my head. It now (sort of) makes sense but I can certainly understand the OP's confusion.

Comment: If it's going to evaluate to get a set accessor, shouldn't the set accessor be to `c`, rather than `b`, and therefore NullRefEx before evaluation of `y` begins? I'm fascinated now I know more about the behavior. I also hope Eric sees this question :-)

Answer (score -1):

I realize this doesn't answer your question, but allowing something outside of class A to initialize a member belonging to class A in this fashion seems to me to break encapsulation. If B needs to be initialized on first use the "owner" of B should be the one to do that.

```
class A
{
    private B _b;
    public B b
    {
        get
        {
            _b = _b ?? new B();
            return _b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is something @Matt Kline wants to do in real life - at least I hope not. The code has several other anti-patterns. However it's an interesting behavior from an academic perspective. Down-voted because this is not an answer to the question - it would have been appropriate as a comment.